# training loss suddenly dropping to zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, loss

guys,
I need some insights for a problem. I tried to implement a neural network for image detection. I am having an issues about training loss dropping to 0.

```
Iteration  22 Losses: 154.892822
Iteration  23 Losses: 106.651184
Iteration  24 Losses: 165.893768
Iteration  25 Losses: 44.355190
Iteration  26 Losses: 8.706368
Iteration  27 Losses: 9704.893555
Iteration  28 Losses: 1405.284546
Iteration  29 Losses: 18458.312500
Iteration  30 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  31 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  32 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  33 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  34 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  35 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  36 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  37 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  38 Losses: 0.000000
Iteration  39 Losses: 0.000000
```

I run the training process for many times, but it always drops to 0 at around step 28.
Does anybody encountered any issue like this? Or could anyone give me some hints, please?

Sincerely

Comment: This could happen for a number of reasons. Why it happens in this particular case is impossible to tell without you sharing your code.

Comment: it look like your model diverges, the loss bounces around but steadily keeps increasing and then it's gone. It should be inf but your code might just display 0

Comment: @dremok I tried to implement SSD based on tf-r1.15 by myself, but I haven't finished this yet. If you have interest and have time, please check the following repo: https://github.com/ylqi007/SSD_TensorFlow_v1.14.

Comment: @Kenan I saw this analysis https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3868#issuecomment-414229497, but I still don't know how to check mismatch.